# How to create quick single-tap iOS webhook "buttons"

Tags: ios, widgets

**TL;DR**: Is there an app (or some other means) that would allow me to create a grid of webhook buttons (**which accept a json string**) that work like the example in this video (i.e. single tap to issue command, no changing of screens)?:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptfxgy9fwlg1rfh/e-Control_example.MP4?dl=0

Note, the beeping in the background is my air conditioner.  I also want the following: if the command to be issued takes a second or 2, I want each tap to queue up the commands in series.  So say I tap 5 times rapidly - I want all those 5 taps to result in 5 webhook calls regardless or how long it takes to issue the command.

The requirement of **accepts a json string** means: not only is there a URL entry for creating the button, but also a text area to enter the content of the json.  I only have 1 webhook URL and different commands are issued based on the json content.

**Background:**

I recently bought a Broadlink RM Mini 3 and while the associated iOS app isn't very slick or pretty, it's highly functional, so much so that it has inspired me to figure out how to create my own remote interfaces that use webhook posts to issue commands.  Here's an example of a custom remote interface I made for my first floor window unit air conditioner using the broadlink app (unfortunately named "e-Control"):

[image]

I have a number of automations setup in Node Red on a Raspberry Pi that I wish to control with webhook buttons.  Many of the automations are also setup in Homebridge and thus, they show up in the Home app, but some simply don't work in the Home app (such as the volume controls for my stereo which I broadcast from my RPi at 27Mhz).

I have webhooks set up (e.g. for the stereo volume) and I can initiate them via Siri Shortcuts - and I even added them to the home screen, but I don't like the widgets interface and using the Siri Shortcuts app is slow and requires multiple taps per volume up/down command.  The closest thing to what I'm looking for is the Siri Shortcuts widget screen.  I also tried creating IFTTT widgets, but that's even slower because it requires 2 chained webhook posts.

So I've been looking for an app or some other way to create "buttons" that issue webhook posts that I can arrange at least in a nice grid like the broadlink app.  It would also be great if it would "queue" the taps so that I can turn up my stereo volume with 5 quick taps, meaning if each tap takes a second or 2 to transmit, all 5 taps eventually get sent in series.

Does anyone know of a way to create webhook buttons like the kind I'm envisioning?

Comment: A webhook is basically an URL, right? Can't you use something like Lauchcenter Pro for this?

Comment: Generally speaking, can you shorten your question to describe in simple terms wha you actually want to do on iOS side? Right now there is a lot of additional information in your post which isn't really relevant for any solution we can offer.

Comment: So I looked into launch center pro. It appears to have the same deficits all the other options I’ve explored have. You can create an action to call a url, but there’s nowhere to enter the json for the post. You can import Siri shortcuts which can send json, but each button you tap switches to the Siri Shortcuts app and slowly plays the script while you watch. I just want to tap volume up 5 times quickly in a row.

Comment: Still not sure I understand what you need, and not sure whether this is something for AD or rather for SO. Putting the question on hold for now, can you please shorten it to the essentials and add an example of a webhook (with all the glory details)?

Comment: I added a TL;DR at the top. I've posted a few times on different sites about this topic. Honestly, I don't think there exists a solution. But what I'm looking for is an iOS app. I thought it worth asking mainly because the app store doesn't typically list capabilities very well. E.g. Many apps that work with iBeacons don't show up when you search ibeacon. 2 of the best iBeacon apps I've found were via posts like this because they show up in no relevant app store search using beacon-related search terms.

Comment: Do you have the option to code everything into the parameters of the http request instead of sending json? Might be easier that way.

Comment: No, hence the requirement

Comment: The question is clear. I addressed your concern, as you requested. The section you claimed was unclear is now under the heading "background", which is relevant to the inspiration/motivation. Please release the hold. If the non-background portion is unclear, please specify how.